# Check if an array is sequentially increasing (the values should increase at each indexes)

Tags: apex, sort

I'm trying to find if array is sequentially incremental.

**Array A** --> {0, 123, 123} This wont be an incremental list as its value is not getting increased sequentially

**Array B** --> {200, 270,800} This is incremental

Logic which I have tried is using bubble sort. I'm sorting the list in ascending order using bubble sort and then finally checking if the original array is same as sorted array. If yes, its incremental. But in this its also taking **Array A** as incremental because after sorting it will remain the same.

Is there any other approach to find if an array is sequentially incremental (At all stages its element should increase (not static))
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use this simple approach:

```
public static Boolean isSequentiallyIncremental(Integer[] items) {

    for (Integer i = 1; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Boolean incremental = items[i - 1] < items[i];
        if (!incremental) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

that passes this test:

```
@IsTest
static void isSequentiallyIncremental() {

    Integer[] a = new Integer[] {0, 123, 123};
    System.assertEquals(false, isSequentiallyIncremental(a));

    Integer[] b = new Integer[] {200, 270, 800};
    System.assertEquals(true, isSequentiallyIncremental(b));
}
```

and avoids the up-front cost of sorting.

Comment: As a developer who has to eventually deal with this problem, please don't teach optional braces. That's a bad habit to get in to.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, If your comment is about skipping the `{ ... }`, I recommend people doing that for the specific case of a single statement on the same line, in this case `if (!incremental) return false;`. Better signal to noise ratio.

Comment: I have counterexamples to that. One was an if statement so long that the next line appeared to be conditional, but was actually an unconditional statement. Another was an if buried in a mess of other statements that were not conditional, so it was hard to spot the logic bug that was there. Yet another was a bad indentation job that only became apparent after using Prettier... If you've never had a problem with it, you can't appreciate them for what they are. Optional braces are not signal-to-noise ratio, they're legibility enhancers.

Comment: @sfdcfox yeah all bets are off on bad code. Personally I'm tying to get away from the verbose, pedantic style I used to use for Java and embrace the more stripped back style of modern languages

Comment: I dislike verbose code, but the braces issue is one thing I keep pointing out. People every day wear seat belts in a car, even if they never have an accident in their life. Why is this? A reasonable safety precaution. Same thing for those braces. But I do avoid actual verbose code, like `List.get` instead of `List[]` and `List<X>` instead of `X[]`. Oh, and absolute worst-case offender: `String.equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're trying to practice/study search algorithms, you should just use the `sort()` method provided by the `List` class. The precise algorithm(s) used are only known to Salesforce themselves, but pretty much *anything* is going to be better than bubble sort.

Assuming the sorting is taken care of, your concern here seems to be figuring out if there are any duplicate elements. A Set would be the natural way to figure that out (since a set will only contain unique elements). Create a set from your list (sorted or unsorted), and if the size of the set is different from the size of the list, you have at least one duplicate item in the list.

```java
// Assumes that givenList is not null
public static Boolean isSequentiallyIncremental(List<Integer> givenList) {
    Set<Integer> setOfGiven = new Set<Integer>(items);
    // sort() modifies the list it is called on.
    // Since we want to check that sort() hasn't altered the original list, we
    //   need to work on a copy of the original list (which is what clone() 
    //   gives us)
    List<Integer> sortedList = givenList.clone().sort();

    return sortedList.equals(givenList) && givenList.size() == setOfGiven.size();
}
```

This approach does take more heap space than simply iterating through the list. The benefit is that it's short and uses standard, well-documented methods. There's very little room for error here.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of the previous value, and if it ever goes down or stays the same, it's not sequentially increasing:

```
public static Boolean isIncreasing(Integer[] values) {
  if(!values.isEmpty()) {
    Integer previousValue = values[0];
    for(Integer index = 1, size = values.size(); index < size; index++) {
      Integer nextValue = values[index];
      if(previousValue >= nextValue) {
        return false;
      }
      previousValue = nextValue;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Sorting and comparing is not ideal. Using Bubble Sort is even less ideal, as the naïve algorithm has an exponential cost factor, and since you need to compare the original list to the sorted list, it's even worse for performance.

Also, given your example, a sort first approach won't work:

```
Integer[] source = new Integer[] {0, 123, 123};
Integer[] sorted = source.clone();
sorted.sort();
System.assert(source == sorted); // returns true!
```

This is because the two 123's will remain in place, thus giving an incorrect result according to your design specifications.

A part of learning programming is to be able to analyze what code is doing (by paper, if necessary) to figure out if it meets the design goals. Any sort-and-compare algorithm won't work given the stated goals.

If you were told that equal values are acceptable, as long as the value doesn't go *down*, then you could use a sort-and-compare algorithm. This means that:

```
{ 0, 123, 123 }
```

Would be acceptable, but:

```
{ 0, 123, 100 }
```

Would fail.

You need to identify boundary conditions and test them against your algorithm to make sure that the algorithm meets your design goals.

Comment: When the array is empty?

Comment: Fair enough. An empty check should be done first. I was more focused on the primary issues with the algorithm, not edge cases.

Comment: Yeah fair enough. I did run your code and it took 63ms for a 1,000 item array whereas mine - more literal to the requirements - took 73ms for the same array. So an interesting example of KISS vs a bit of optimisation.